# How to get file names included in a list file depending on strings read from one more file?

Tags: batch-file, subroutine

I have text file `testsuite.txt` which contains records, i.e. test suites value:

```
ProductABC_TestSuite.txt
ProductDEF_TestSuite.txt
ProductHIG_TestSuite.txt
ProductIJK_TestSuite.txt
```

I have another file `product_to_test.txt` which contains:

```
ABC, IJK, HIG
```

I need to split and read the value from `product_to_test.txt` and get the corresponding right test suite from `testsuite.txt`.

For example:

1. If product is `ABC` then it should fetch the test suite `ProductABC_TestSuite.txt`.
2. If product is `ABC, IJK` then it should fetch `ProductABC_TestSuite.txt` (space) `ProductIJK_TestSuite.txt`

I have tried the following code. But it is **NOT** working:

```
for /F "tokens=*, delimiter=," %%A in (product_to_test.txt) do (
    call :sub %%A
)

:sub
    SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
    set product=%1
    set "test_suite="
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (testsuites.txt) do (
        set str=%%A
        Echo.!str! | findstr /C:"!product!">nul
        if !errorlevel!==0 set test_suite=!test_suite! !str!
    )
    echo %test_suite%
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all spaces between ABC, IJK, HIG in product_to_test.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works based on the "**examples**" you provided.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p strings=<product_to_test.txt
set strings=%strings:,=%

for /F "delims=" %%A in ('findstr "%strings%" testsuite.txt') do (
    set "test_suite=!test_suite!%%A "
)
echo %test_suite%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more commented batch script which does not use the command **FINDSTR**.

```
@echo off
rem Are both files existing in current directory?
rem Exit batch job if one of the two files is missing.
if not exist "testsuite.txt" exit /B
if not exist "product_to_test.txt" exit /B

rem Setup a new environment for the remaining processing. This environment
rem is discarded with command endlocal which restores previous environment.
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "TestSuites="
set "Products="

rem Assign first line from products file to a variable.
rem All other lines are ignored if there are more lines.
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%P in ("product_to_test.txt") do (
    set "Products=%%~P"
    goto ProcessProducts
)

:ProcessProducts
rem Was the file not empty?
if not "%Products%" == "" (
    rem Split this line up and search for each product in test suites file.
    for %%P in (%Products%) do call :GetTestSuite "%%P"
)

rem Was any test suite file name found at all?
if not "%TestSuites%" == "" echo The test suites are: %TestSuites%

endlocal
exit /B

rem Search in test suites file for first file name containing the
rem product name of current product to test and when found append
rem it to the test suites variable. The first one is not appended
rem to avoid a space at beginning.

:GetTestSuite
set "Product=%~1"
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%T in ("testsuite.txt") do (
    set "Suite=%%T"
    if /I not "!Suite:%Product%=!" == "%%T" (
        if "%TestSuites%" == "" (
            set "TestSuites=%%T"
        ) else (
            set "TestSuites=%TestSuites% %%T"
        )
        goto :EOF
    )
)
goto :EOF
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`